# Can Exact Match and StopwordsFilter mix in Solr

Tags: solr, tokenize, stop-words, exact-match

I'm rephrasing my earlier question. Hoping someone will be able to help.

I currently have a solr implementation that do exact matching only.

Therefore, a search phrase of "THE TEST" will match only to "THE TEST"

However, I've also implemented pattern replace filter.

So a search phrase of "TOM AND JERRY" will match with "TOM & JERRY".

Now, we want to add stopwordsfilter. We want to remove "THE" during indexing.

Therefore, a search phrase of "TEST" will match with "THE TEST".

I change the tokenizer from KeywordTokenizerFactory to Whitespacetokenizerfactory. However, the search result blew up.

Although "TEST" is now matching with "THE TEST". It also matched with "EVEL TEST" and etc.

Is there a way to avoid the test phrase from matching with evel test and etc?

Help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Below is my current index analyzer

```
 <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="(&amp;)" replacement="AND"/>
 <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="(@)" replacement="AT"/>
 <charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="(['_\(\)])" replacement=" "/>
 <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
 <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
 <filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([~!#$%*+`?/|,.;:}{&lt;&gt;&quot;&#039;\^\=\]\[\\\-])" replacement="" replace="all"/>
 <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true" enablePositionIncrements="false"/>
```

Comment: After several tinkering. It appears combining exact search and stopfilter is like oil and water.

Comment: After several tinkering. It appears combining exact search and stopfilter is like oil and water. First, I'm using KeywordTokenizerFactory tokenizer to create one token only for exact match. Now, stopwords, are taken out if they found a match on the token created. For example, I have a search phrase of "the test". my stopword is "the". Since I used keyword tokenizer, it only creates one token "the test". Therefore, the stop word "the" will not match with "the test". To make the stopfilter work, you need a different tokenizer like whitespaces to create two tokes "the" and "test" to make it work.

Comment: However, it defeats the purpose of the exact match if I used a tokenizer other than keyword.. search result will blew up. Anyone knows a work arounds, besides pre-processing the stopwords outside solr or adding server patternfilters after token which may not be viable if we have too many stopwords.